# Optimal solution to extract value from line using Grep

Tags: sed, grep, line, extract

Could you please tell me what is the optimal way to extract idle value from this line using grep?

```
CPU states:   0.1% user,   0.1% system,   0.0% nice,  99.8% idle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` should do the trick:

```
top -n 1 | grep "idle" | awk '{ print $9 }'
```

Since the idle-percentage is the ninth value, it's `$9`.

Comment: The `grep` is superfluous, `use awk '/idle/ { print $9 }'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` alone:

```
grep -Po '[0-9.%]+(?= idle)'
```